# Reformat old raspbian install from SD card seems impossible

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

So I have this old pi 1B+ and I thought, let' just clean this guy up. It's been serving me for a few years as SSH entry point to my other pies etc.

However I'm unable to get the thing re-partitioned, tried on windows machines using all sorts of tools, also made an ubuntu boot stick and tried gparted,...

Nothing seems to work. Whatever I do, it seems to work fine, but when I plug the ting back in, it's just back to bone stock. As if nothing had happened.

Is there maybe a way to wipe the whole thing while logged in to it?

Edit: it's not set to read-only mode either

The sd card has worked just fine before I pulled it out.

Comment: If you use fdisk, do not forget to use the `w` command to actually write the planned changes to the partition table..

Comment: fdisk just said "partition list altered" or something, but when I mount the disk again. Back to where I started.

Comment: Did you run `sudo resize2fs <partition>` after a reboot? I recall that being the finalizing step [as described here](https://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions#Manually_resizing_the_SD_card_on_Raspberry_Pi)

Comment: the SD cart contains the boot partition and root dir of the OS, I'm doing this on external machines

Comment: Ah, if you are not booted in to raspbian there is no reason for the reboot, just running `sudo resize2fs /dev/sdsomething` right away should work

Comment: but that's just to resize a disk right? not to wipe it?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of that command is to resize, i have used it before myself on a pi that was booted from usb (the raspi-config resize is for sdcard only) with success

Comment: I'm not so sure what that would do, I think the thing is just dead or damaged somehow

Comment: I can confirm from personal experience that resize2fs does not wipe any data when used as intended, it just resizes the data on the disk as specified in the partition table, it does not format the partition.

Comment: exactly, so how will that help me?

Comment: Sorry, i thought you wanted to resize and not format the sdcard, so when you asked if the command was to resize and not to wipe i thought you were afraid of dataloss. For a wipe use the `g` option in fdisk which creates a new partition table, then use `w` to write the changes

Comment: I ended up buying a new SD card, I think the one I was using might have gone bad some how as nothing I did would result in changes (read only was off, both in the hw slider and card itself)